# Determining the group for a monit process

Tags: chef-infra, monit

I'm using chef & monit to spin up a group of workers like so:

```
check process delayed_job
  with pidfile /srv/www/blog/shared/pids/delayed_job.pid
  start program = "/bin/su - deploy -c 'cd /srv/www/blog/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec script/delayed_job start
  stop  program = "/bin/su - deploy -c 'cd /srv/www/blog/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec script/delayed_job stop
  group delayed_job_blog
```

And then when I do `sudo monit status` I get the following:

```
Process 'delayed_job'
  status                            running
  monitoring status                 monitored
  pid                               5758
  parent pid                        1
  uptime                            7m 
  children                          0
  memory kilobytes                  64648
  memory kilobytes total            64648
  memory percent                    6.3%
  memory percent total              6.3%
  cpu percent                       0.0%
  cpu percent total                 0.0%
  data collected                    Thu Jul  3 22:57:38 2014
```

However, the group is not listed. Is there anyway way, without stopping and starting the process, to determine if the group has been set correctly?

Comment: Oh, I kind of left that out, I'm using chef to generate monit.

  template "/etc/monit.d/delayed_job.monitrc" do
    source "delayed_job.monitrc.erb"
    mode 0644
    variables(deploy_to:    deploy["deploy_to"],
              user:         deploy["user"],
              current_path: deploy["current_path"],
              rails_env:    deploy["rails_env"],
              application:  application)
    notifies :restart, "service[monit]"

Comment: Please update your question instead of posting a comment.

Answer (score 0):

just to check if group 'delayed_job_blog' has been set correctly without restarting, 
you can run:

```
sudo monit -g delayed_job_blog status
```

if you see output like:

```
Service group 'delayed_job_blog' not found
```

then the group has not been set correctly.